# Fetch last record based on field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm a learner and new at mongo. I'm trying to fetch the last records according to particular field. In SQL `select * from powerandlevel group by deviceId order by desc limit 1`. So in this SQL query based on deviceId I can get the last record of every deviceId. Same I want do in mongodb

```
[{
_id: "ObjectId(6246ab45e95eac6c85726cfc)"
imageName: "IMG_123456.jpg"
eventTime: "2022-04-01T07:35:30.615Z"
deviceId: "48701ED21819"
},
{
_id: "ObjectId(6246ab45e95eac6c85726cfc)"
imageName: "IMG_123456.jpg"
eventTime: "2022-04-01T07:38:10.543Z"
deviceId: "58701ED21819"
},
{
_id: "ObjectId(6246ab45e95eac6c85726cfc)"
imageName: "IMG_123456.jpg"
eventTime: "2022-04-01T08:05:50.865Z"
deviceId: "48701ED21819"
}]
```

And I'm using this query `db.imageEvent.aggregate([{ "$group" : {"_id" : { "deviceId" : "$deviceId"}}}, {$sort: {eventTime: 1}}, { $limit : 1 }])`

Result

```
[{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "58701ED21819" } },
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "48701ED21819" } }]
```

And expecting a result like this

```
[{
_id: "ObjectId(6246ab45e95eac6c85726cfc)"
imageName: "IMG_123456.jpg"
eventTime: "2022-04-01T07:38:10.543Z"
deviceId: "58701ED21819"
},
{
_id: "ObjectId(6246ab45e95eac6c85726cfc)"
imageName: "IMG_123456.jpg"
eventTime: "2022-04-01T08:05:50.865Z"
deviceId: "48701ED21819"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the `ObjectId` of each result, just the common values and the latest date, you can simplify it by:

```
db.imageEvent.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$deviceId",
      imageName: {$first: "$imageName"},
      eventTime: {$max: "$eventTime"},
      deviceId: {$first: "$deviceId"},
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oyVCwevEQqT)
The `$first` is convenient for values that are the same for the group. The `$max` will give you the latest date.

This will prevent you from sorting the entire collection and from creating large documents during the query, since there is a cap size for a document.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$sort` - Sort by `eventTime` DESC.
2. `$group` - Group by `deviceId` and take first document into `data` field via `$first`.
3. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document with `data`.

```
db.imageEvent.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      eventTime: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "deviceId": "$deviceId"
      },
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bt1XYJHymXE)